# creating macros in intellij

Tags: macros, intellij-idea

I am trying to create a macro that takes a selection of text and runs some find/replace on it using a regex.  I have recorded this macro in intellij, but when I run it, all I get is the find/replace dialog opened. No find/replace is executed.

Has anyone had any luck with creating a *find/replace* macro in intellij?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/using-macros-in-the-editor.html is very helpful

Comment: I used to utilize AutoIT on Windows for creating macros. It is a very powerful macro. If you use Windows, maybe you can try it just for workaround.

Comment: if you already have the regexp and replacement in the find/replace dialog/bar then close the bar and just use the hotkeys (f3) to select the next occurrence using the last item entered in find/replace. then (ctrl+r) to do the replacement. Afterwards, some stuff will be selected, so you need to hit esc otherwise the next f3 will try to find the selected text and you want it to keep using the old regexp.

Answer (score 3):

I can't get get the macro find/replace to work either but I can give you two things that might solve your problem:

1. If it is only a few places/times you need to do it find/replace has memory of earlier replacements (arrow down in search/replace fields).
2. Write a plugin (yes seriously it is not hard at all) to do this. I was surprised how easy it was, even though the documentation could be improved.

And a bonus way of doing it, I just thought of:

3. Open the file in Emacs record replacing macro (or write an elisp function to do it), this is the way I would have done it until I learned how easy it was to make Idea plugins.

Comment: can you put your plugin code online by chance, i think that would be extremely helpful to everyone ;)

Comment: I don't have a general search/replace plugin (I have some other functions that I missed from Emacs). But if I get some time off I will write one.

Comment: @osundblad have you write the plugin yet?

Comment: Thank you for suggesting to write a plugin. I did that in only I guess 2 hours. And now I know how it works

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a [long-standing bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-59382) in IntelliJ. One workaround that worked for me was this:

- Install the [IdeaVim plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164?pr=idea).
- When recording a macro requiring searching, enable Vim mode (Tools -> Vim Emulation) during the macro, position the cursor using standard Vim measures, disable Vim mode.

In general, Vim emulation can be really handy for IntelliJ macros.

Answer (score -4):

If all else fails, tou could try [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/), [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), [Applescript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript) or [other general-purpose macro systems.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:GUI_automation)